# What's the syntax for stating user and password when curling to Artifactory

Tags: command-line, artifactory

I'm trying to push artifacts to Artifactory (on Linux) and struggle with the whacky syntax. As I understand it there are multiple different ways to achieve this. I've kind of settled on this:
`curl -uMyUser:MyPassord {...}`
All stated without quotes. I've managed to make it push once, however since then I've fiddled around with it and keep getting a bad credentials error.
Is there a more robust way of doing this, preferably so that control sequences within the password don't cause me additional trouble, since I post the password unquoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deploy using the below curl command to Artifactory,

> curl -u myUser:myPassword -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/file.txt" -T myNewFile.txt

If it fails with bad credentials, are you using any special character in the password?

Otherwise, the best approach is to [generate the API Key](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Profile#UserProfile-APIKey) and use it as below in the curl,

> curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API_Key_here>" -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/file.txt" -T myNewFile.txt

In this way the password issue should be resolved plus API Key ensures proper coating of your password and username.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!